how to dismiss keyboard and not bottom sheet when user click on barrier
In flutter, how to use showModalBottomSheet with isDismissible:true to close keyboard when user tap on modal barier or if keyboard is not displayed close the bottom sheet ?
By default flutter pop both, i would like to handle one then handle the other.

You need to detect the keyboard is visible or not, then you can use PopScope to control ModalBottomSheet's dismiss action
class SheetWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SheetWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<SheetWidget> createState() => _SheetWidgetState();
}

class _SheetWidgetState extends State<SheetWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver{
  var _isKeyboardVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    final bottomInset = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom;
    final newValue = bottomInset > 0.0;
    if (newValue != _isKeyboardVisible) {
      setState(() {
        _isKeyboardVisible = newValue;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: !_isKeyboardVisible,
      child: Center(
        child: TextField(
          onTapOutside: (ev) {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

